# MS Access DMax limitation in form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a simple but large database, and an imput form which shows "last date entered" and uses =DMax("[Date]","[Revenue and Counts Data]")

This has worked fine for years but recently it won't go past 9/9/2016 even though I see dates past that one in the database.

Is there a row limit on this (getting near 65K rows) or something else I am missing?

Comment: There is no DMax bug that I know of. Is it possible to create a simple [mcve] (for example, by creating the table data programmatically with a loop) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Is "[Revenue and Counts Data]" a table or a query?

Comment: If you create and run a query `SELECT Max([Date]) AS MaxDate FROM [Revenue and Counts Data]`, what does it show?

Comment: Have you run a compact and repair on your database. I've seen errors in queries before where there's a corrupted record in the dataset. Can you view the table and do a sort ascending and sort descending on the Date field? You also seem to be using a reserved name for your field name - not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing dates as text which is a no-no.

So either convert your field to data type *Date* or use this expression:

```
=DMax("CDate([Date])","[Revenue and Counts Data]")
```

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion? (Maybe I'm blind...)

Comment: It's the *9*. It will - as text - for any month/year be sorted as "the highest".

Comment: Ah, logical. :)  I only wonder because John wrote *This has worked fine for years*. We'll see when he comes back.